# How to keep track of what object belongs to which object?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, data-structures

Disclaimer: This is a school project but Prof said it's ok to ask for help.

The project is to simulate a traffic grid. The part I'm working on is keeping track of what car is on what road. A road is an array list containing cars. 
I've made a road handler (an array list) that contains all roads.

```
public void checkPositionOnRoad(){
    if(this.getPosition() > RoadHandler.currentRoad.getLength()-this.getCarLength()){
        RoadHandler.currentRoad.remove(this);
        Road nextRoad = moveToNextRoad(RoadHandler.currentRoad);
        nextRoad.accept(this);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to keep track of "currentRoad". Getting the next road is easy enough because I can just say

```
nextroad(Road currentRoad);
```

where I just grab the currentRoad's index+1.

The end goal is for the car to finish it's road and move on to the next one in the array of roads which RoadHandler keeps track off. So while the car runs it checks to see where its on in the road. Once it finishes it's road it takes itself out of the current Road and adds itself to the next one.

```
public void run(double time) {
    checkPositionOnRoad();
    position += velocity;
}
```

Also I want to reset the car's position on the new road. 
The checkPositionOnRoad and run methods are in the Car class and the nextRoad method is in the RoadHandler class.

Comment: what do u mean by keep track of currentRoad ?!

Comment: Sorry. By current road I mean what road the car is currently on as opposed to the next one it will eventually move on to. Since I don't know what to do with it, it's currently null.

Comment: honestly i cant understand what exactly do u want...

Comment: Not sure there's enough information here to help much. You must know the currentRoad, there's a `currentRoad` reference?

Comment: So in the RoadHandler class I made an instantiated currentRoad to null just so it would compile but right now it's just a place holder so that there's no errors.

Comment: let me know if my answer was useful :)

Answer (score 0):

Easy. Create a [POJO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_Old_Java_Object) class to represent you cars objects. And create an attribute in that class called currentRoad. Like this

`String currenRoad;`

The current road attribute should be changed each time you car enter to a new road. it implies that you need to create a POJO class to represent you road objects. Always remember design you problem before do coding

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? You mean like have a boolean that switches every time we move to a new road and then update the string to reflect the new road. But road isn't a string so I don't know how that would work?